# Rsync unhides files when syncing

Tags: macos, rsync

When I tell rsync to sync 2 folders with `-a /source/path/ /destination/path`, hidden files become suddenly visible. Is there a way to tell rsync not to unhide those files, but simply copy the folder as it is. Just like you would in a do by hand in a regular file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` doesn't preserve file flags by default. Add `-E` to preserve extended attributes, file flags, ACLs, and resource forks.

If rsync was installed via homebrew, `-X` has to be used instead.

Comment: Adding `-E` doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: It works for me at least back to 10.7. If you're using the standard non-OS X version of `rsync` (like the one installed by `brew install rsync`), use `-X` instead of `-E`.

Comment: That was it. Forgot that I have installed the newer version via homebrew. `-X` worked. Thanks!